# Shadow Displayed in IE9 Highcharts

Tags: javascript

How to remove shadow of plot points in highchart.It doesnt have problem in ie8 and ie but in ie9 it displayed shadow.

Comment: Hi rahul i tried shadow:false in plot options but its not working at all

Comment: hi Rahul here is my code i am doing like this plotOptions: {
    series: {
     shadow: false,
     fillColor:{
      linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 30],
      stops: [
       [0, 'rgb(212, 233, 252)'],
       [1, 'rgba(2,0,0,0)']
      ]
     },
     fillOpacity: 0.75,
     marker: {
      radius: 3,
      fillColor:'#0095da',
      lineColor:'#0095da',
      lineWidth: 2,
      states: {
       hover:false
      }
     }       
    }},
   legend: {
               enabled: false
  },
  series: []
  
  };

Answer (score 0):

try adding `stacking:"normal"` like:

```
plotOptions: {
series:{ stacking:"normal", shadow: false, 
fillColor:{ linearGradient: [0, 0 0 30],
stops: [ [0, 'rgb(212, 233, 252)'], [1,rgba(2,0,0,0)] ];
}
```